# How to combine 3 firebase observables without losing dynamic updates

Tags: firebase, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I have a 3 parallel firebase requires. And I need to join them as 1 single object. Code as below:

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2";
import {Thread} from "../model/thread";
import {Message} from "../model/message";
import {Participant} from "../model/participant";

constructor(private  http: Http, private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

loadUserThreads(uid): Observable<AllUserData> {
return Observable.forkJoin([
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/threads').first(),
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/messages').first(),
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/participants').first()
])
  .map((data:any[]) => {
    let threads: Thread[] = data[0];
    let messages: Message[] = data[1];
    let participants: Participant[] = data[2];
    let AllUserData = {
      threads: threads,
      messages: messages,
      participants: participants
    }
    return AllUserData;
  })
  }
```

This work and return the exact format I need, which is with this interface:

```
export interface AllUserData {
  participants: Participant[];
  threads: Thread[];
  messages: Message[];
}
```

The problem is forkJoin won't run without .first() all the firebase observables. And if I use .first() to complete all the firebase observables, I LOST the dynamic updates which why I use firebase the first place. How can I get the best of both world? - Keeping the firebase observables live but can join them like my interface format? I am pulling my hair out on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `.forkJoin(...)` you could use [`.combineLatest(...)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest).

I also did *streamline* your `map` a bit:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/threads'),
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/messages'),
  this.db.list('participant/' + uid + '/participants')
)
.map(([threads, messages, participants]: [Thread[], Message[], Participant[]]) =>
  ({ threads, messages, participants })
)
```

Comment: Haha! It is @olsn again here come save the day!!! Thank you so much. Yes, but simply switch to combineLatest work... I wonder tho will the order of the array will change depend on which observables emit first? I read somewhere forkJoin keep the order of the different observables and combineLatest is not?

Comment: The order should always stay the same with combineLatest, just like forkJoin

Comment: Cheers for this!

Comment: it will only work if all of those three nodes in the database are not empty. If they could be empty you should use .merge

Comment: @Nikolay_R are you sure it won't return `null` or `undefined` in that case? I would assume that you still get an answer - even if it's an empty one

Comment: @olsn yes, i am sure. `this.db.list('list_name').valueChanges` emit no value for empty node. As a result `zip` and `combineLatest` operators will not emit value too.