# firestore query filter based on a collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `book` collection in firestore, by design each document has an `id` (say it's integer ids like 0, 1, 2..); I want to query the collection by filtering a *random* collection of document `id` e.g. [2, 5, 23, 54], note that these ids are random so I can't use range filter like `isGreaterThan`.
I want to avoid querying once for each filtered id as it may read the database too many times (which can be costly).

I tried to use `Firestore.instance.collection('book')where('id', array_contains:[ filtered id])` but this doesn't work since `id` isn't a collection field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cant do `or` queries in `array_contains` its definitely a feature people want and so id recommend logging your [feature request with support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/). However in the meantime because your queries wont intersect it's the same cost to just do individual queries and bring the results together into a main array. Not sure on your language so cant give an example but its just doing 4 queries in your example and having them all update a master array.

Comment: can you give an example using Java or JS please?

Comment: Certainly, this stackoverflow answer has a good example, its for the realtime db but its the same concept - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785378/1614889

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on "queries won't intersect it's the same cost to just..." Are you saying doing multiple reads costs the same as reading once (if the query is supported)?

Comment: You are basically doing 4 gets in your query as you want 4 specific documents. So if you do 4 specify gets for those documents thats 4 reads. If that query existed to do an or it would return 4 results which is 4 reads. So the same price. The only time it could get more expensive is if you were doing a query for documents that have x tag or y tag and then you could have duplicates which would cause more reads from the db.

Comment: oh, so if the ideal query does exist, it would effectively do 4 reads anyway hence the cost is the same as me reading each 4 doc individually? Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: Correct. You are charged for the documents read from the database not the query

Comment: you can add the id of the document as a field inside of it, and use  the ID field in the filter.