# Joining two firebase observables

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am using angularfiredatabase. I am trying to join my product and my product-branch. I want to get the quantity from my product-branch to the product. Heres the [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMubn.png) 0 there is the KEY of my branch

```
findAllProductsForBranch(branchName:string):Observable<any[]> {

  const products$ = this.findProductsByProductKeys(this.findProductKeysPerBranch(branchName));
  products$.map((products) => {
    products.forEach((product) => {
      product.map((product) => {
        Object.assign(product, 
        {
          quantity: 
           this.db.object(`/products-branch/0/${product.$key}`)
           .switchMap(product => product._quantity)
       })
      })
    });
    //return products;
  })
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
  return Observable.of([]);
}
```

products$ contains an observable of products without the quantity, so i want to add a quantity but the question is how? When i run this code undefined is displayed in the console. Im stuck here for almost a week now

Comment: is this the package you're using? https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: Yes dude thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, thanks to cartant he explained it here [Fork join two firebase observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319673/fork-join-two-firebase-observables)

```
findAllProductsForBranch(branchName:string, branchKey: string):Observable<any[]> {
  const products$ = this.findProductsByProductKeys(this.findProductKeysPerBranch(branchName));
  return products$.mergeMap((products) => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            // Map the tours to the array of observables that are to
            // be joined. Note that forkJoin requires the observables
            // to complete, so first is used.

            products.map((product) => this.db
                .object(`/products-branch/${branchKey}/${product.$key}`)
                .first()
            ),

            // Use forkJoin's results selector to match up the result
            // values with the tours.

            (...values) => {
                products.forEach((product, index) => { product._quantity = values[index]._quantity; });
                return products;
            }
        );
    });
}
```